# Internal Server Error connecting XMPPHP to Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: php, android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I am on my way to implement server side code for my social application, I am going to use XMPPHP to send downstream messages to android apps. I am able to do this using HTTP, but I am looking to implement XMPP protocol.

Below is the code I have which is giving "Internal Server Error"

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('lib/XMPP.php');
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP(
                'fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com',
                5236,
                'my_reg_id@fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com',
                'my_server_id',
                'xmpphp', 
                'my_domain', 
                $printlog=True, 
                $loglevel=LOGGING_INFO);
    $conn->connect();
    $conn->processUntil('session_start');
    //$conn->message('Regid', 'This is a test message!');
    $conn->disconnect();
```

?>

Please suggest how to debug this or what may be going wrong?

Comment: Please include the full response.